# assign max and min to alertify number prompt

Tags: javascript, html, alertifyjs

I need to assign max and min values to Alertifyjs number prompt.

I have this:

```
alertify.prompt( 'Prompt Title', 'Prompt Message', 'Prompt Value',
    function(evt, value) {
        alertify.success('You entered: ' + value)
    }
    , function() {
        alertify.error('Cancel')
    }).setting({
        type    : 'number',
        min     : 8,
        max     : 30,
        value   : 8
    });
```

But it does not work for me.

Comment: Is any error in the console?

Comment: No @TamilSelvanC, no error in console. I inspected the input and it did not assign the properties

Answer (score 3):

Inspecting Alertifyjs's [Prompt page](http://alertifyjs.com/prompt.html), it looks to me like `min`, `max`, and `value` are not valid settings.

If all you need is to bound the value, maybe just use some `if`s:

```
var min = 8;
var max = 30;

alertify.prompt( 'Prompt Title', 'Prompt Message', 'Prompt Value',
  function(evt, value) {
    if (value < min) {
      console.log("your value is too low");
    } else if (value > max) {
      console.log("your value is too large");
    } else {
      alertify.success('You entered: ' + value)
    }
  },
  function() {
    alertify.error('Cancel')
  }).setting({type: 'number'});
```